# How to implement 'Typing...' in android chat app using firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created sample chat app using firebase. User can log in via gmail and can chat with other user.

Now I want when user A is typing, I want to display User B as 'User A is typing...'

How Do I do that?

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: Here's a tiny one I did for JavaScript a while ago: http://jsbin.com/cociyi/edit?html,js,output  Translate it to Android code and you're in business.